# A bulletproof super Soldier who can Dodge bullets?

Tags: biology, creature-design, super-powers

I also need to combine two suggestions about changing a person's muscle fibers so that my genetically modified person has both of them.
The first sentence refers to the modification of human muscle fibers in the manner of "Kevlar" so that the bullet does not hit the internal organs.
The second sentence describes changing the structure of a person's muscles, ligaments, and nerves to be able to Dodge bullets.

In other words, I need to combine the above human modifications into one.

(1) First sentence:

"In order for the reaction time to be fast enough to Dodge a bullet, we will have to increase the speed of nerve conduction from a certain speed, measured in just meters per second, to a speed close to the speed of light. Metal cores and sheathed nerves would fulfill this requirement. Then we will have to replace the slow diffusion signaling mechanism of the nerves with something much faster... That is, instead of relying on chemical diffusion, we could have a mechanical connection between the nerves. This may be a mechanism in the transmitting neuron that, after receiving the appropriate electrical signal, rotates by a certain amount and that is physically connected to the sodium gate, which also relies on rotation to be open. A mechanical connection means that the transfer rate will not occur at the rate of chemical diffusion ( the average speed of a nerve impulse is), but at the speed of sound in the connecting rod. ( the speed of sound is  )

By reducing the reaction time of the brain and nerves, the main limiting factor will be the muscles and the body. Mammalian muscles are relatively slow. Although there are some things that can be done to speed up the speed of muscle contraction and reaction time. The problem is that it is unlikely that the muscles will be able to contract at a rate much greater than we have in normal muscle fibers. However, there are alternatives.

The nature of the muscles is such that they must contract gradually, a few micrometers at a time, but when relaxed, they can be stretched by external forces much faster. So to maximize the speed at which the limb can bend, we can increase the ratio of joint to muscle and joint to load, so that less effort is applied, but applied faster. In addition, in the directions most likely to evade, we can completely replace the muscles and replace them with a highly elastic combination of muscles and ligaments. In a stressful situation where rapid movement may be required, the stronger antagonist muscle will contract along with the weaker agonist muscle, stretching the elastic ligament. Then, if it is necessary to evade, the corresponding antagonist muscles can be deactivated, resulting in the stored energy in the elastic ligament being applied to the joint much faster than the muscles are capable of on their own. In addition, it would be possible to have both a powerful antagonist muscle and a smaller muscle-elastic ligament in each direction of movement to provide two "gears" for each direction of movement, slow and powerful, and weak but fast.

Yes, this Superman capable of successfully dodging bullets is unlikely to look like an ordinary person. After all, muscles have mass, and the smaller the mass, the easier it is to move. Instead, expect to see a creature with long, thin limbs and a thin body that looks more like a gray alien than a human.

However, despite its apparent slimness and fragility, this creature could not only Dodge with superhuman speed, but could also be an incredibly dangerous martial artist. Although its limbs could weigh half as much as the average human, it could reach a limb speed of perhaps ten times that of a human. Given the ratio between the impact energy, mass, and speed, equal to e = 1/2 MV^2, half the mass is equal to half the energy, but ten times the speed is equal to a hundred times the energy, for the total impact energy is fifty times greater than that of a person. This slender, lanky, and fragile-looking creature could literally kill a man with a single blow.

Of course, adapting this creature requires it to be aware of a potential attack in order to evade it. When threatened, he crouched, and his muscles tensed, keeping his limbs half-bent as he stretched the elastic ligaments. He could see the nearest opponent's finger on the trigger, or see the flash of a shot from a longer distance, and within milliseconds he could deactivate the opponent's muscles, elastic ligaments clenching to get him out of the line of fire.

Of course, if this creature were caught flat-footed, it would not have the advantage that energy would accumulate in its elastic ligaments, and given the likely energy needs associated with keeping the elastic ligaments stretched, it would not be able to walk with them permanently pre-stretched. In such a case, it would be much more likely that he would be hit by an incoming bullet, although he may be able to achieve a less serious hit. »

(2) the Second sentence :

"This means that they are made of parallel fibers optimizing their ability to pull along their required vector. Along this angle, you can punish them all you want with relatively little risk of injury. However, bullets tend to hit the muscles on the sides, which allows them to squeeze through the muscle fibers with relatively little force. If the muscles were woven more like Kevlar, they would be extremely difficult to penetrate. Unlike thicker or harder muscles, woven muscles will not significantly reduce flexibility, but you may suffer from a slight decrease in the pull force, since you are no longer pulling straight.

Perhaps the best option for a natural armor that doesn't seem less human would be to strengthen your person's entire body with a Dura mater .

The Dura mater is the outermost protective membrane that covers your brain and spine. It is exceptionally strong, flexible, and made from irregular cross-woven fibers. A report from the new Jersey public health system shows that the Dura mater of rats can withstand 1.3 million Pascals of stress, which is a lot, especially given their size. By layering the Dura mater between your skin and striated muscles, your person will look, feel, and move very much like an ordinary person, but when fired from a small-caliber cartridge, the Dura mater fibers will distribute the impact over a large cross section of muscle instead of allowing it to simply pierce between them. With distributed impact, your muscles can do what they do well and contract.

By distributing the impact over a larger surface, you would probably tear the skin, a lot of bruising, and some serious muscle inflammation after the shot, but the bullet would be much less likely to be able to hit the main organs.  »

In short, I need to combine the two above modifications of the human body into one. So that my genetically modified person has the two abilities listed above.

Comment: If you copy-pasted those sentence from somewhere else, please cite the source and use the appropriate formatting

Comment: I'll look at the first modification in detail later, but the second one could be made easier. If you can weave strands of spidersilk into your skin you can prevent penetration of the skin. It'll leave bruises and some broken bones depending on what you are hit with.

Comment: The enemy will respond by using ammuntion that the super-soldier is not designed to protect against ("break out the flamethrowers"), scaling up the impact energy release of each projectile until it overcomes the super-soldier's design ("break out the large-caliber armor-piercing ammo"), and scaling up the volume of projectiles to make dodging ineffective ("lead with the machine guns"). These three old-school approaches, together, seem cheaper and faster to implement than developing and fielding the super-soldier...their own super-strength folks reduced to carrying all the extra ammunition.

Comment: Genetics can only do so much for one’s body, capabilities, skill ceiling, and durability under stress. However, if you want your soldier to be capable of dodging bullets, you’d need some serious workarounds with human neural pathways and brain size. Flies, for example, perceive time 10x slower than we do. Reaction time can be increased in humans through faster and shorter neural connections (see flies again, also catfish), but actually moving one’s body equal to your quicker senses is what makes or breaks it.

Comment: Also, metabolic rate matters a lot if these super soldiers cannot turn off their new perception of the world. If you solve the brain to body transmission problem, your soldiers will also be living much shorter lives due to their massive increase in energy requirements. They will be hungry quicker and more often without them realizing it, which is a strain on supply lines.

Comment: Can you tell us more about increasing the transmission rate of the nerve impulse ? ( how can it be accelerated 10 times?)

Comment: You have cited (unattributed) two solutions. You haven't tagged this science-based. The solutions don't seem to interfere one with other. So just implement them, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Kevlar or other similar material is very limited for bullet stopping  - anything serious (NIJ 3+ iirc) will need hard armor inserts.

Larger  caliber rounds  (.50) or specialty armor piercing rounds which go through 20mm or more of steel plate cannot be stopped by body armor.

Comment: I need to combine the two above messages about changing the human structure. I need biological solutions.

Your answer is absolutely not suitable!
( I need a natural armor, but not a shell, keratinized tissue, or scales )

Comment: move this message to the comments.

Comment: @FrenchThompson People have been trying to crack this one for decades and there are some fundamental problems -- especially with people making better bullets.

Comment: I need to combine the two solutions listed above so that one doesn't interfere with the other. Your answer does not answer me this item.
( I know that there are bullets that can reach higher speeds and need more reliable protection. But if you want to offer a solution to this problem, I need a biological solution. I already know about the normal and strong bulletproof armor that soldiers wear )

Answer (score 1):

Skin partially composed from graphene would certainly be capable of absorbing bullet impact; being held together by continuous covalent bonds, graphene has far more strength than any normal organic material, and although it would be unlikely for something like that to develop naturally due to the necessary graduality of evolution, it could theoretically be developed through genetic modification.

Answer (score 0):

People dodge bullets all the time in movies, and they don't even try, they just run normally and the bad guys miss while wasting hundreds of dollars worth of bullets.

You need plot armor.